# Client side Reporting UI

Tags: graphql

I have a set of endpoints I will be building using GraphQL and will expose to the clients over Azure APIM and having authentication methods implemented. I would also like to give said client a UI where they can build the query them selves and possibly play around the results of their query. Is there something already built out there that has this functionality.

Mainly I would like to give non technical users the ability to build their own query by possibly having a list of available attributes on one side and once selected the query is built for them.